# how to make cells invisible without moving others in a row

Tags: html, rows

I'm trying to add a cell to a row but making other cells not visible moves the cell down in order.  For example:

```
      var celltwo = row.insertCell(0);
      var cellthr = row.insertCell(0);
      var cellfr = row.insertCell(0);
      var cellfv = row.insertCell(0);
      var cell = row.insertCell(4);
      celltwo.style.display = 'none';
      cellthr.style.display = 'none';
      cellfr.style.display = 'none';
      cellfv.style.display = 'none';
```

This will put cell into the first column because setting the .style.display to 'none' will remove them.  Is there a way to keep them there but not make visible in any way...borders,background,so forth?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Does `cellfv.style.visibility = 'hidden';` give the effect you want?

Comment: Visibility -> hides item while maintaining it in document flow. Display -> hides and removes from document flow.

Comment: Well there are still outlines of the cells I entered.  Doesn't look like there were hidden completely.